# Paths in a finite graph

Tags: graph-theory

If we use the standard definition of a path in a graph, is it possible that there exists an infinite path in a finite graph?

Comment: The answer to your question is no, but riddle me this: 
Let $\mathcal{T}$ be the infinite (complete) binary tree (that is, a rooted tree where every vertex has exactly two children). 
Let $v$ be the root of $\mathcal{T}$, and consider an infinite path rooted at $v$. How many such paths exist within $\mathcal{T}$?

Comment: @Tim Lee: Look up the definition of **walk** (in contrast to **path**). If your finite graph has at least one edge, then this graph has also at least one infinite walk.

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible; if you were able to find such a path, that path would by definition have to traverse an infinite number of distinct edges and thus would have to hit infinitely many vertices, which is a contradiction.  Of course, by definition, a finite graph has finitely many (distinct) edges.